# Why is Mr. Bennet "prodigiously proud" of Wickham?

Tags: jane-austen, pride-and-prejudice

Over the course of Jane Austen's *Pride and Prejudice*, Mr. Bennet makes several references to how much he likes Wickham:

> 'He is as fine a fellow,' said Mr Bennet, as soon as they were out of the house, 'as ever I saw. He simpers, and smirks, and makes love to us all. I am prodigiously proud of him. I defy even Sir William Lucas himself, to produce a more valuable son-in-law.'
> <sub>*Pride and Prejudice*, chapter 53</sub>

> Elizabeth had the satisfaction of seeing her father taking pains to get acquainted with him; and Mr Bennet soon assured her that he was rising every hour in his esteem.
> 'I admire all my three sons-in-law highly,' said he. 'Wickham, perhaps, is my favourite; but I think I shall like *your* husband quite as well as Jane's.'
> <sub>*Pride and Prejudice*, chapter 59</sub>

In the novel, Wickham is established as a rather scummy individual; he runs off with Lydia with no intention of properly marrying her, and it's only due to the pressure (and money) from Mr. Darcy that he does end up actually marrying her. Mr. Bennet is well aware that Wickham didn't immediately plan on marrying Lydia, having gone off to London to look for him.

Why, then, would Mr. Bennet make not one, but multiple statements about how much he likes Wickham? I would normally read the statement in chapter 59 as being sarcastic, but the statement in chapter 53 is muddying the waters a bit; Mr. Bennet, unprompted, starts praising Wickham, stating that he is "prodigiously proud" of him. It seems an odd statement to make after all that Wickham's done, even jokingly.

What's going on with these statements? What does Mr. Bennet mean by these?

Comment: At the end of chapter 1 we learn Mr B  was "a mixture of quick parts, sarcastic humour, etc", so maybe it is irony (in the sense of  words expressing something other than their literal intention, often in a humorous context).

Comment: I would say it was definitely sarcastic.